# Jhipster Login page instead of home page

Tags: jhipster

I want to allow any user to see Jhipster generated Home page (or any other page) only after they have logged in.

How do I make the login prompt appear first?

Comment: Take a step back for a second and pretend you're someone else, reading this question for the first time. Would you understand what the OP is going on about? You need to give us some context, show us what you've already tried, maybe read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) while you're at it.

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [Authorizations](https://jhipster.github.io/using-angular/#Authorizations) in the JHipster documentation.

In short, you need to modify the [angular `route`](https://angular.io/guide/router) for your particular page, in this case the home page located in `src/main/webapp/app` and depending on whether you chose to use [Angular4](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/master/generators/client/templates/angular/src/main/webapp/app/_app.route.ts) or [AngularJS](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/master/generators/client/templates/angularjs/src/main/webapp/app/_app.state.js). You need to add the base authenticated user role `'ROLE_USER'` to the `authorities` array.

Comment: I am using Angular4 and added the 'ROLE_USER' to my home.route.ts file as shown below  
`import { Route } from '@angular/router';`  
`import { UserRouteAccessService } from '../shared';`  
`import { HomeComponent } from './';`  

`export const HOME_ROUTE: Route = {`  
    `path: '',`  
    `component: HomeComponent,`  
    `data: {`  
        `authorities: ['ROLE_USER'],          <-- added role `  
        `pageTitle: 'Welcome, Java Hipster!'`  
    `}`  
`};`  
It is not working as expected still home page is showing up without login. Any thing else I need to do apart from this?

Comment: praavi you need to add canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService] after